# Kendo combobox - jQuery val() not triggering viewmodel value change

Tags: jquery, kendo-ui

I have a lot of kendo comboboxes in my page. I am having some problem with clearing values (""); I am using code like this:

```
$('#clearAll').click(function () {       
        $("#params input").val("");        
    });
```

With this, I'm trying to clear values of all inputs on my page. But, this only clears visible values, when I check values in viewmodel, they are still unchanged.

So I thought, change event needed to be triggered, so I used:

```
$("#params input").trigger("change");
```

But still the same. I not quite understanding value binding rules in kendo's MVVM. Is this a normal behaviour, or a bug?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you stay true to the MVVM pattern, then what you should do is change the value on the ViewModel, not the View (combobox).

> Clear Button (on view) -> call "clear" function (on ViewModel) -> call viewmodel.set("field", "") -> triggers an update of the combobox (on the view)

---

If you want to just do it the way you already are, then instead of calling jQuery's `.val()` function, try using the Kendo ComboBox's `.value()` function instead: http://docs.kendoui.com/api/web/combobox#value

So possibly try changing your code to:

```
$("#params input").data().kendoComboBox.value("");
```

Comment: There is also a problem with viewmodel.set() function. It clears all my values in viewmodel, but some values stay the same on view side (values stay visible to user). Only thing I could think of, is that some other event is messing with set() change event. Any advices?